# imshow top axes lables without twiny?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have a single row of data that I want to heat-map it without the use of twiny(), because it will have alignment problems.
I have searched a lot in this site and thats what I've reached till far:

[image: imshow with single row heat map]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = "0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6".split(",")
y = "180, 175, 170, 169, 150".split(",")
z = [[5000, 4800, 4500, 4450, 4300]]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

image = z

im = ax1.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar(im)


ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(x)), minor=False)

ax1.set_xticklabels(x, minor=False)
#ax1.set_yticklabels(y, minor=False)

ax1.tick_params(labelbottom='on',labeltop='on', labelleft="off")



plt.show()
```

As you can see, the top axis has exactly the same text as the lower axes.
What I want is to put `y` in the above axis.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

It seems that `twiny` and axes with aspect ratio set to `equal` do not want to live on the same axes. To me it seems like a bug, but there may be an explanation.

So, let us get around this problem by plotting two axes on top of each other. This is not as trivial as it sounds, because if two subplots are at the same position, `matplotlib` interpretes them to be the same one. However, using `add_plot` there is no such problem.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = "0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6".split(",")
y = "180, 175, 170, 169, 150".split(",")
z = [[5000, 4800, 4500, 4450, 4300]]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

image = z

im = ax1.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar(im)

ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(x)), minor=False)
ax1.set_xticklabels(x, minor=False)
ax1.tick_params(labelbottom='on',labeltop='off', labelleft="off", 
    top='off', left='off', right='off')

# create another axes on the same position:
# - create second axes on top of the first one without background
# - make the background invisible
# - set the x scale according to that of `ax1`
# - set the top ticks on and everything else off
# - set the size according to the size of `ax1`
ax2 = fig.add_axes(ax1.get_position(), frameon=False)
ax2.tick_params(labelbottom='off',labeltop='on', labelleft="off", labelright='off',
    bottom='off', left='off', right='off')
ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(len(y)))
ax2.set_xticklabels(y, minor=False)

plt.draw()
ax2.set_position(ax1.get_position())

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

The `plt.draw()` is needed before the `set_position` as otherwise the `get_position` will return wrong position for `ax1` due to the use of `equal` aspect. (This may be the very reason why `twiny` fails.)

[image]

---

If you need to have several rows, the solution is not that different:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = "0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6".split(",")
y = "180, 175, 170, 169, 150".split(",")
z = [[5000, 4800, 4500, 4450, 4300]]

numRows = 8

fig, subaxes = plt.subplots(nrows=numRows, ncols=1)
axeslist = subaxes.flatten()

for ax in axeslist:
    im = ax.imshow(z, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, interpolation='nearest')

    ax.tick_params(labelbottom='off',labeltop='off', labelleft="off", labelright='off',
                   bottom='off', top='off', left='off', right='off')
    if ax == axeslist[0]:
        ax.set_title('Avg. (s)\n', size=13)
    elif ax == axeslist[-1]:
        ax.tick_params(bottom='on', labelbottom='on')
        ax.set_xticks(range(len(x)))
        ax.set_xticklabels(x)

# reserve some space between the subplots
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.07*(numRows-1))

# create the overlay images, add them as extra properties of the original images
for ax in axeslist:
    axnew = fig.add_axes(ax.get_position(), frameon=False)
    axnew.tick_params(labelbottom='off',labeltop='on', labelleft="off", labelright='off',
                   bottom='off', top='on', left='off', right='off')
    axnew.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())
    axnew.set_xticks(range(len(y)))
    axnew.set_xticklabels(y)
    ax.extra_axes = axnew

# update the secondary axes positions
# draw() only if there was something changed (important!)
def update_secondary(event=None):
    position_changed = False
    for ax in axeslist:
        if ax.extra_axes.get_position().bounds == ax.get_position().bounds:
            continue
        position_changed = True
        ax.extra_axes.set_position(ax.get_position())

    if position_changed:
        plt.draw()

# register the secondary axes updater as a callback
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', update_secondary)

# make sure everything is drawn
plt.draw()
```

[image]

As the overlay update has to be carried out after everything else has been drawn, it is here done by the `draw_event` from the backend. The result is that after the image is redrawn for some reason, the overlays are readjusted, and if any positions were changed, the scene is redrawn.

This works but is not beautiful.

Comment: although am not that good in matplotlib, but I've understand something about the drawing thing in it; thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have a quesion @Drv, how to add another row (with different data) below the first row, but with the same colormap?

Comment: I know this :), but what I want is to have another row with the same down values, but different top values :)

Comment: @AbdulMomenعبدالمؤمن: See the new edit. (For the colorbar issue, see my answer to your other question. These are eay to combine, but if you abandon `axis='equal'`, then you may use `twiny` which is much easier.) The solution outlined above is an ugly way to get around a bug in `matplotlib`.

Comment: Ah! great :) I've got two problems when using the code; 1st: when having more than 3 rows (e.g., 8), the top row labels get intertwined (try it); and 2nd: when I scale the figure horizontally, the top labels are displaced (also try it); and I've added the colormap, but it effects the last row only. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found an alternative solution by using text instead of changing the axes values.

[image: imshow single top and bottom labels without twiny]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

font = {'family' : 'sans-serif',
        'color'  : 'k',
        'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 12,
        }

x = "0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6".split(",")
y = "180, 175, 170, 169, 150".split(",")
z = [[5000, 4800, 4500, 4450, 4300]]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
#fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

image = z

im = ax1.imshow(z, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, interpolation='nearest')
xticks = ax1.get_xticks()

top_lables_width_spacings = 0.83
top_lables_hight_spacings = -.53

for i in range(len(y)):
    ax1.text(xticks[i] + top_lables_width_spacings, top_lables_hight_spacings, y[i], fontdict=font)
#ax1.set_aspect('auto')

fig.colorbar(im, orientation='vertical')

ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(x)), minor=False)
ax1.set_xticklabels(x, minor=False)

ax1.tick_params(labelbottom='on',labeltop='off', labelleft="off")

ax1.set_title('$\eta$\n', size=17)      # represents the top axes label
plt.xlabel(r'$\theta$', size=17)                        # represents the bottom axes label
plt.show()
```

Comment: In the qustion code, don't use twiny(), but use twin() instead and it will solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `twin()` and `from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import numpy as np

x = "0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6".split(",")
y = "180, 175, 170, 169, 150".split(",")
z = [[5000, 4800, 4500, 4450, 4300]]

#fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1 = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)

ax2 = ax1.twin()
image = z

im = ax1.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar(im)


ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(x)), minor=False)
ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(len(y)), minor=False)

#ax1.tick_params(labelbottom='on',labeltop='on', labelleft="off")
#ax2.tick_params(labelbottom='on',labeltop='on', labelleft="off")

ax1.set_yticklabels([])
ax2.set_yticklabels([])

ax1.tick_params(labelbottom='on',labeltop='on', labelleft="off")


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got this right, I guess you just need to change x to y:

```
ax1.set_xticklabels(y, minor=False)
```

If I do that, I see labels in list y on the top and bottom of the plot.

Comment: Now it gives me the y values for both up and down. I want the x values down and the y values up.

Comment: What was the problem with twin? it looks like twin should do the same to me. http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/simple_axisline4.html

Comment: Ah!, thanks @ottreb, I was using twiny() instead of just twin().

Comment: oh, there are twinx twiny too. i did not know that. good to know... glad that it helped anyway :)